# What is the connection between outer product, quadratic form and definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization

In proving whether a function is convex or concave, I frequently encounter people who ends their analysis on something the sort:

> Since $\nabla^2 f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & b a\\ ab & b^2
>  \end{bmatrix}$ is an outer product of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b
>  \end{bmatrix}$ therefore $f(x,y)$ is convex

Can someone clarify what is this so special about outer product that we can make quick statements such as this? Is it true that every single hessian that can be expressed as an outer product is positive semidefinite?

Comment: $\nabla^2$ means $\nabla \cdot \nabla$, aka div grad, aka the Laplacian. You mean the Hessian, $\nabla \nabla f$.

Comment: And see my question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436593/221811), which basically answers what you're asking.

Comment: @WillJagy On the contrary: take the vectors $u_i$ as living in $\mathbb{R}$, with the inner product $\langle a,b \rangle=ab$. This is exactly what the OP has. In that case, they're all proportional, so you do get the equality case.

Comment: @Chappers, alright. Notation seems ambiguous to me, but there you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If $\nabla^2f(x,y)$ is positive semidefinite for all $x$ and $y$, then $f(x,y)$ is convex.

2) If a matrix can be written as an outer product, then it is positive semidefinite.

So, Hessian is outer product implies $f$ is convex.

Note that this is a special case where the Hessian is necessarily rank 1, which is *not* a positive *definite* matrix. More generally, $f$ is convex if and only if its Hessian is positive semidefinite.
On the other extreme, if $\nabla f = UU^T$ for some matrix $U$, and if $U$ is square and full rank, then $\nabla^2 f$ is positive *definite*, and $f$ is *strongly* convex.

Comment: What is the justification for (2)?

Comment: If $A = UU^T$ then $x^TAx = \|Ux\|_2^2 \geq 0 $ for any $x$.